# OpenCL compiler preprocessing definitions?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, opencl

I am developing OpenCL code on Snow Leopard and understand that the OpenCL just-in-time compilation is done by Clang/LLVM. Is the C preprocessor used at all? Is there a way to set preprocessing definitions with the compiler? What definitions exist?

I would like the code to be aware of whether it is compiled for CPU or GPU so I for instance can use printf statements for debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `clBuildProgram` API takes compiler arguments (the `const char * options` parameter).

`-D MYMACRO` is understood, so is `-D MYMACRO=value`.

As to what predefined macros, see the OpenCL specification for a full list (Section 6.9). A non exhaustive list:

- `__FILE__`
- `__LINE__`
- `__OPENCL_VERSION__`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the OpenCL "preprocessor" to define definitions (like in C):

```
#define dot3(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) ((x1)*(x2) + (y1)*(y2) + (z1)*(z2))
```

(notice the brackets, they are important because you can insert any Expression in the Variables and the expression gets correctly evaluated)

This helps to improve the speed of your Application.