# kernel function parameter as const

Tags: c++, c, cuda

say I have a kernel

```
foo(int a, int b)
{
    __shared__ int array[a];
}
```

it seems a has to be a constant value, I added const in front of int. It sill didn't work out,
any idea?

```
foo(const int a, const int b)
{
    __shared__ int array[a];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't have a dynamically-sized array because of the constraints of the C language (as mentioned in other answers), what you can do in CUDA is something like this:

```
extern __shared__ float fshared[];

__global__ void testShmem( float * result, unsigned int shmemSize ) {
    // use fshared - shmemSize tells you how many bytes
    // Note that the following is not a sensible use of shared memory!
    for( int i = 0; i < shmemSize/sizeof(float); ++i ) {
       fshared[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

providing you tell CUDA how much shared memory you want during kernel invocation, like so:

```
testShmem<<<grid, block, 1024>>>( pdata, 1024 );
```

Answer (score 3):

In ISO C++ the size of an array needs to be a so-called *constant expression*. This is stronger than a const-qualified variable. It basically means *compile-time constant*. So, the value has to be known at compile-time.

In ISO C90 this was also the case. C99 added VLAs, variable-length-arrays, that allow the size to be determined at runtime. The sizeof operator for these VLAs becomes a runtime operator.

I'm not familiar with CUDA or the `__shared__` syntax. It's not clear to me why/how you use the term *kernel*. But I guess the rules are similar w.r.t. constant expressions and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CUDA or OpenCL let you dynamically allocate shared memory. Use `#define` macro instead.

If you need a dynamic sized array on a per program basis, you can supply it using `-D MYMACRO` (with OpenCL, I don't know for CUDA). See Bahbar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545510/opencl-compiler-preprocessing-definitions).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can *statically* allocate a `__shared__` array of `n` values in CUDA using C++ templates

```
template <int n>
kernel(...)
{
    __shared__ int array[n];
}

const int n = 128;
kernel<n><<<grid_size,block_size>>>(...);
```

Note that `n` must be a known constant at **compile time** for this to work.  If `n` is not known at compile time then you must use the approach Edric suggests.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect this is a C language question.

If it were C++, you could simply use `std::vector`.

```
void foo( int a, int b )
{
    std::vector<int> array( a );
    // ...
}
```

It if really is C++, then what C++ features you can use safely may depend on the environment. It's not clear what you mean by "kernel".